# Unable to trigger Javascript with Flask app

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm starting to learn Flask using WTForms and inevitably some of the things I want to do require AJAX and Javascript code.  I am trying to execute a Javascript function on a SelectField when the dropdown box is clicked and an option selected.  It doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why...  I am using an external .js file which does appear to get loaded when I look at the Chrome developer info.  Here is what I have for my HTML and javascript files.

**start.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.dev_models.label }}{{ form.dev_models }}<br>
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.dev_count.label }}{{ form.dev_count }} <br>
        </p>
        <p>
            {% for device in devices %}
            {% if form.dev_models.data == device.model and device.stackable %}
            {{ form.dev_stacked.label }}{{ form.dev_stacked }}<br>
            {% break %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/modelSelection.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**modelSelection.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('dev_models').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/modelSelection',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If I move the JS inside the HTML file, it works....  if it is in an external file, it doesn't.  I do see the .js file get downloaded.  Never seems to get executed when I click on the select field.

Comment: Are you sure your selector is correct? `$('dev_models')`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to wrap your modelSelection.js in a jQuery document ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

This way your function will load when all other code is loaded.

Edit: Where did you define the HTML id of dev_models?